# Comparing part of a list to full list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, compare

I want to compare two lists that had been previously split and matched up again.

I have two lists. the unsplit one and the split one

```
 list1 = ['store1 120', 'store2 140', 'store3 160', 'store4 150']
 list2 = [120, 140, 150, 160]
```

the second list has already been turned into ints and sorted by size. I want to see if i can compare the two lists so since 'store1 120' has the most in common with '120' and will return the whole string so it can be split again and return just the store name. How can I compare these two lists to return the most similar? Most searches just return single integer lists which are not very useful.

Edit:
to clarify I needed something that could take a number from an already modified list and return an associating location on a similar list. The original list can and will vary so it needed to be dependent on the input rather than predefined definitions.

Comment: by *most in common with* did you mean *equals* or were you looking for the numbers to match within some tolerance or maybe find the store with the *closest* number?

Comment: 'most in common' is a very imprecise term.  You're getting a lot of mixed answers as a result.  Please clarify what you mean, as @wwii says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to consider

1. Your first list is just a concatenation of the name and a number which is present in the second list.
2. The Number is always at the end of the string
3. Searching a list for each item in your first list is not quite efficient

Solution

1. To Solve (1) and (2), Just perform a right partition on space and extract the name and the number
2. To Solve (3), use a set instead of a list

**Demo**

```
>>> list2 = [120, 140, 150, 160]
>>> set2 = set(list2)
>>> for e in list1:
    name, _, num = e.rpartition(' ')
    if int(num) in set2:
        print name


store1
store2
store3
store4
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what worked. It's plug and play rather than relying on definitions. I need to use a varying set of data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want a dictionary of store numbers to store names. You can do that by just using `list1`.

```
>>> d = dict([z.split() for z in list1])
>>> d
{'store4': '150', 'store3': '160', 'store2': '140', 'store1': '120'}
```

Now you just need the inverse of that.

```
>>> inv_map = {int(v):k for k, v in d.items()}
>>> inv_map
{160: 'store3', 120: 'store1', 140: 'store2', 150: 'store4'}
```

Now you can use `list2` to get the store name or just go through the key value pairs.

```
>>> for x in list2:
...   print inv_map[x]
... 
store1
store2
store4
store3
```

Comment: Lots of issues and redundancy in your code. 1. dict accepts a generator expression, so you don't need to pass in a list. 2. You can easily reverse the split-ted pair in your first expression 3. You are assuming that the name would not have spaces. Somewhat in lines of `dict(z.rsplit()[::-1] for z in list1)` would had been more suitable.

Comment: @Abhijit I really appreciate the response. This was just the order of my thoughts when looking at the problem. And I agree this isn't the best approach as you clearly pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary (hash/map), as you split the list, store the items in a lookup dictionary,

```
#You have:

list1 = ['store1 120', 'store2 140', 'store3 160', 'store4 150']
list2 = [120, 140, 150, 160]

#While building list2, build lookup,

lookup = {}
lookup[120]= 'store1 120'
lookup[140]= 'store2 140'
lookup[150]= 'store3 150'
lookup[160]= 'store4 160'
print "store: "+str(150)+", "+lookup[150];

#delete one,
del lookup[160];
```

Answer (score 0):

No mention of efficiency in the quest for an answer so for every number in list2 see if there is a store in list1 with that number.

```
list1 = ['store1 120', 'store2 140', 'store3 160', 'store4 150']
list2 = [120, 140, 150, 160]

for number in list2:
    for store in list1:
        if str(number) in store:
            print 'number:', number, 'store:', store.split()[0]
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
number: 120 store: store1
number: 140 store: store2
number: 150 store: store4
number: 160 store: store3
>>>
```

If you just need to sort the store names by their number use list.sort().

```
list1.sort(key = lambda item: item.split()[1])
print '\n'.join(item.split()[0] for item in list1)
```

Comment: Freddie's answer is pretty slick and you'll be better off with it if you do this a lot.